# I have a getText error

Tags: java, swing

After compiling the code below, I get the error `Could not find symbol` on that line which contains `String str = getText(jtf)`.
I Checked the java docs but i could not understand the syntax.
Please help me as i am a complete beginner. Thanks!

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

class Frame implements ActionListener 
{
    Frame()
    {
        JFrame jf = new JFrame("Welcome");
        Container c = jf.getContentPane();
        JPanel jp = new JPanel();
        c.add(jp);
        JLabel jl = new JLabel("Please enter your name");
        jp.add(jl);
        JTextField jtf = new JTextField(30);
        jp.add(jtf);
        String str = getText(jtf);
        JButton jb = new JButton("Submit");
        jp.add(jb);
        jb.addActionListener(this);
        jl.setForeground(Color.black);
        jf.setBounds(200,200,400,400);
        jf.setVisible(true);
        jf.setDefaultCloseOperation(jf.EXIT_ON_CLOSE); 
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae)
    {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Welcome"+str);
    }

    public static void main (String[] args)
    {
        Frame f = new Frame();
    }
}
```

Comment: Please learn about [Classes and Objects](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/), before proceeding on your endeavour. If you are not been able to catch, such a thingy in your code, why you riding on a `Swing` horse !!!

Comment: @nIcEcOw He states that he is a complete beginner, I think it's a fair question. But I agree, the link you provided is a useful to read as a beginner. Although as as a complete starting point.

Comment: @brimborium : A beginner is not suppose to work on a `Swing`. What happens when one talks about `Event Dispatcher Thread` sort of thingies, a beginner will know nothing of threads too, and all GUI Frameworks rely on that heavily :-) Though if you look at OP's previously posted question, you will know, how important that link is, since OP appears to me is lacking the core stuff and is trying to touch some high level stuff. __Learning is always a slow process, one cannot just reach the cliff in one step :-)__

Comment: @nIcEcOw I think there are different ways to approach a language. For instance, Mine certainly **isn't** to start off with *HelloWorld.java*. The most important thing (imo) that you are motivated. And that is a very individual experience.

Answer (score 5):

It's

```
String str = jtf.getText();
```

not

```
String str = getText(jtf);
```

To fix the `String` `str` error you need to make the variable a class instance variable. Better yet just make the `JTextField` `jtf` a class instance variable and retrieve the text from that.

```
public class FrameTest implements ActionListener {


    private JTextField jtf;

    FrameTest() {
        JFrame jf = new JFrame("Welcome");
        jf.setDefaultCloseOperation(jf.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        JPanel jp = new JPanel();
        jf.add(jp);
        JLabel jl = new JLabel("Please enter your name");
        jp.add(jl);
        jtf = new JTextField(30);
        jp.add(jtf);
        JButton jb = new JButton("Submit");
        jp.add(jb);
        jb.addActionListener(this);
        jl.setForeground(Color.black);
        jf.setVisible(true);
        jf.pack();
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Welcome" + jtf.getText());
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                FrameTest f = new FrameTest();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

This will ensure that the text displayed in the `ActionListener` reflects the current content from the `JTextComponent`.

Comment: Thanks. now the error points out to the variable str which is used in the dialog box. Please help.

Comment: Thanks again but the error still persists. Now it points to 'jtf'.

Comment: @ChinmayDabke Btw, I suggest using useful variable names (like `JButton submitButton = new JButton("submit");` instead of something like `jb`. It makes the code much more readable.

Answer (score 2):

Replace this

```
String str = getText(jtf);
```

with

```
String str = jtf.getText();
```

as getText method belongs to [JTextField](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/text/JTextComponent.html#getText%28%29) class inherited from [JTextComponent](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/text/JTextComponent.html#getText%28%29).

Answer (score 2):

It should be:

```
String str = jtf.getText();
```

This is because the `getText()` is a method of `JTextField` object.

Comment: Thanks. now the error points out to the variable str which is used in the dialog box. Please help.

Answer (score 2):

You made a silly mistake :)

Instead of

```
String str = getText(jtf);
```

do

```
String str = jtf.getText();
```

Comment: The error says could not load symbol for the variable str in the dialog box.

Comment: that's odd, what are you putting into the str variable? (what is the result of `jtf.getText();`?